Python file runs perfectly with python3 command but when compiled with cython stops working
my python script runs perfectly with python3 command.
i usecython main.py --embed to convert my python file to c file
it output the c file and this:
/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:381: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using '3str' for now (Py3). This has changed from earlier releases! File: /home/solid/PythonAuthenticator/main.py   tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)

then i use to turn it to a binary
PYTHONLIBVER=python$(python3 -c 'import sys; print(".".join(map(str, sys.version_info[:2])))')$(python3-config --abiflags) gcc -Os $(python3-config --includes) main.c -o pyauth $(python3-config --ldflags) -l$PYTHONLIBVER

but when i run the binary, output this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 87, in init main
    key_id: str = typer.Argument(None),
TypeError: Expected str, got ArgumentInfo

this is the part of the function that is in the line 87 (i use Typer for this program):
@app.command()
def show_code(
    key_id: str = typer.Argument(None), 
    issuer_name: str = typer.Option(None),
    e: bool = typer.Option(False, help="Show TOTP code of a key outside key file.")
):
...

i used pyinstaller and it works, but the binary is too big and slow, idk what i should do

so you are saying that the type should be str but in reality the type is actually ArgumentInfo from typer. You just seem to be using the wrong types

The difference is that, by default, Cython checks the types of your annotations so they have to be correct. You can turn that off with the annotation_typing directive.

Note also that Cython --embed doesn't bundle dependencies (unlike pyinstaller) so you may find that the extra size of pyinstaller really is needed

thx DavidW i added # cython: annotation_typing = False at begin of my file, now the binary works, but some functions dont, all the function that have something similar, like this key_id: str = typer.Argument(None), issuer_name: str = typer.Option(None) dont work

Note: the only function that not work after the # cython: annotation_typing = False that contain something like this key_id: str = typer.Argument(None) was because a misspell

DavidW's comment helped:

The difference is that, by default, Cython checks the types of your annotations so they have to be correct. You can turn that off with the annotation_typing directive.

I added this at the beginning of my file and now it works:
#cython: annotation_typing = False
#cython: language_level=3

I'm going to make a setup.py for a more organized code.
